# Struts2 - menu and including page

Tags: jsp, menu, struts2

I have got a basic question regarding Struts2. I want to implement a simple web application in the next style:

```
                           TITLE                 12:42
------------------------------------------------------
MENU              | **********************************
1. Config         | **********************************
 - Products       | **********************************
 - Customers      | **********************************
2. Operations     | **********************************
 - ...            | **********************************
3. Statistics     | **********************************
```

Please forgive me, I am not a web designer. :)

So my web application has got a title and additional information (e.g. current time) will be put on the header part. On the left side there will be a menu and on the right side (which will occupy the 80% of the display) will appear a page (I indicated it with the many stars) depending which menu has been choosen on the right. After login the right side will be empty and if the user clicks on a menu the specific page appears there.

I would like to use Struts2 to control the page flows.

Could you please give me some idea how to start?

Thanks,
V.

Comment: Really I don't know how to explain this :)
Try to look into the Struts flow here.
http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/the-struts-2-request-flow.data/Struts2-Architecture.png .   I don't see this as the basic question in struts but you can definitely construct the page step by step.

Comment: RoseIndia provides a good tutorial for struts2. Hope this help. If you still need any details kindly let us know.
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/

Comment: Try integrating apache-tiles as suggested by Umesh.

Comment: Thanks, Raja and Quaternion! My web app won't have sophisticated pages so I only need a container web page and include a header, menu and right panel web page and control the content of right side with OGNL expression. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is most likely a question related to design and layout control and you have few good options here

1. User Struts2 with JSP and control view based on the user inputs
2. Use some decoration framework like Site-mesh or Tiles

you can create an application frame or master template which can define following sections

1. header
2. top navigation
3. left panel
4. right panel
5. footer
6. working area

in above all of sections can be predefined except working area which can be changed at run time by sending view based on your application logic.

for me Tiles is a good way to go and it will do many things for you in a easy and flexible way.

Comment: Hi Umesh! Thanks, this is what I need! I created a container web page and include a header, a left panel (menu) and a right panel page in it. I added a page property to the actions and refered to this property in the include tag: <s:include value="%{page}"/>

Answer (score 0):

My solution in the end:

index.jsp

```
<body>
   <table border="0">
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><s:include value="header.jspf"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><s:include value="menu.jspf"/></td>
         <td><s:include value="%{page}"/></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

struts.xml

```
<package name="menu" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="menu_admin_freq" class="org.vhorvath.throttling.web.actions.MenuAdminFrequencyAction">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/jsp/index.jsp</result>
    </action>   
</package>
```

Action class

```
public class MenuAdminFrequencyAction extends ParentAction {
    private String page;    
    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }
    public String execute() {
        page = "/jsp/frequency.jspf";
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

Menu.jspf

```
<table border="0">
   <tr>
      <td><b>Administration</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align="left"><a href="menu_admin_freq.action">Frequency of ...</a></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommand you to use Sitemesh as a template generator, very useful